# how to fix "Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read" error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a simple node setup and Im trying to read a directory in my mac, but i seem to get an error, previously there was no error. Im confused whether i should change yarn setting or not

the error im getting ->
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

```
var folder = "/Users/rahul/cosmos/repo/fonts/ofl"

try {
    let files = fs.readFileSync(folder)
    console.log('the files ------>', files)
} catch(e) {
    console.log('the error is ---->', e)
}
```

Comment: There should be a path to the file not to the folder. Is "ofl" file or a folder?

Comment: it is a folder.

Comment: Please give the file path. Folder path won't work.

Comment: yeah, you are right. It's working now

Answer (score 0):

Removing empty directories in the same path made it work